# Rails no longer allows "symbol: value" in routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax-error

so I just updated my system from os 10.6.8 snow leopard to the shiny new mountain lion and I am finding a whole slew of the exact same error message from rails:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
```

What gives? I used to do stuff like dependent: :destroy and validates presence: true, uniqueness: true   all the time, but now I can no longer do it?

I guess it makes sense that the code should be verbose but I actually kinda liked the conciseness of the previous code that ran without flaws on my old system.

I ran into this right away when getting my rails app up and running on my routes.rb wherein I discovered that doing

```
root :to => 'welcome#index', as: 'welcome'
```

would no longer work and rails required `:as => 'welcome'`

Has anyone had a similar experience? Is there a way to recover this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new hash syntax comes form ruby 1.9.

Check your ruby version by `ruby -v`

Comment: kwiggint$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]